# I'm receiving an error on a foreign key constraint when trying to create a table with multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
Student_Clinic_STD_DB.Visit

 (
  `Room_id` INT NOT NULL,


  `P_ID` INT NOT NULL,


  `Dr_ID` INT(4) NOT NULL,

  `Time_Date` DATE NOT NULL,

  `N_ID` INT(6) NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`Time_Date`),

  INDEX `Room_Id` (`Room_id` ASC) VISIBLE,

  INDEX `Dr_id_idx` (`Dr_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,

  INDEX `N_Id_idx` (`N_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,

    FOREIGN KEY (`Dr_ID`)

    REFERENCES `Student_Clinic_STD_DB`.`Doctors` (`Dr_ID`));

    **FOREIGN KEY (`N_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Student_Clinic_STD_DB`.`Nurses` (`N_id`)**

ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The line in bold is what is triggering the error. The error says that foreign is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, Alter etc..

Comment: Where is one valid? What would it have to look like to be there? Why are you indenting? What is minimal code giving the error?

Comment: Try removing semicolon after `(`Dr_ID`));`